# Como transferir as checkboxes selecionadas para um campo input hidden?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Eu tenho uma caixa de seleção de checkboxes que seleciona várias cidades e preciso que os valores selecionados entrem dentro de um `value` de um `input hidden`. O exemplo do que eu preciso [pode ser encontrado aqui](http://www.evoximoveis.web1437.kinghost.net) clicando em ***Bairros***.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **O que eu já fiz: na hora que clica no input ele abre um popup com os bairros ...**

```
<div class="col-md-2 third-field-search">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['bairro'])){ ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" id="bairro" placeholder="Bairros" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['bairro']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBairros" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">
<?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" class="form-control" placeholder="Bairros" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBairros" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

> **Dentro do POPUP tenho isso:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="todos-bairros">
        <input id="z885ar" name="todos[]" class="marg0 ckeck-checkbox" value="" type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;REGIÃO 1<br>
    </div>
    <input name="bairros[]" class="z885ar" value="Bairro1" type="checkbox">Bairro 1<br>
    <input name="bairros[]" class="z885ar" value="Bairro2" type="checkbox">Bairro 2<br>
    <input name="bairros[]" class="z885ar" value="Bairro3" type="checkbox">Bairro 3<br>
    <input name="bairros[]" class="z885ar" value="Bairro4" type="checkbox">Bairro 4<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puder usar jQuery, fica algo assim:

```
$('.classDosCheckBox').click(function () {

    var $hidden = $('#idDoInputHidden'); 

    if(this.checked)
        $hidden.val($hidden.val() + ',' + this.value);
    else {
        $hidden.val($hidden.val().replace(',' + this.value, '');
    }
});
```

Essa é uma ideia da solução, serve como ponto de partida para alcançar o que precisa.